# Linear complex functions

Tags: complex-dynamics

$L_{\alpha}(z) = \alpha z$ where $z$ is a complex number and $\alpha$ is a constant and is also complex.

How do I prove for $|\alpha|<1$ all orbits tend to a unique limit and how do I find this limit?

Comment: Here's a hint: Try to compute an explicit formula for the $p^{\text{th}}$ iterate, $L_{\alpha}^p(z)$.